# How can I clone all the repositories of an Azure project?

Tags: bash, git, azure-devops, repository

I need to clone all the existing repositories in an Azure project to perform some searches. Then try the following code:

#!/bin/bash

```
ORGANIZATION="abc"
PROJECT="cdf"
PAT="fgh"

az devops login --organization "https://dev.azure.com/$ORGANIZATION"

REPOS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n :$PAT | base64)" \
  "https://dev.azure.com/$ORGANIZATION/$PROJECT/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0" \
  | jq -r '.value[].sshUrl')


for REPO in $REPOS; do
  git clone $REPO
done
```

But I get the following error for all attempts:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cloning into 'some-repo'...
remote: Public key authentication failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The token I'm using is correct, I actually used it today to clone repos send commits etc.
What am I doing wrong? or what other approach can I use.

Comment: That error isn't about the API token you're using, though - it's about the SSH key. Is it available to the script?

Comment: Oh God it's true! I thought I was using HTTP, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Bash script like as below:

The sample here is using the Azure CLI '[**`az repos list`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-list)' command to list all the accessible repositories from the specified project.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

org="{organization}"
proj="{project}"
pat="{PAT}"

az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/$org <<EOF
$pat
EOF

repos=$(az repos list -p $proj | jq -r '.[].remoteUrl')

for repo in $repos; do
  echo "Clone repository: $repo"
  git clone "$repo"
done
```

[image]

Comment: @DiegoL, Is there any update from you?